# ASP.NET Web Sitio sin respuesta en IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

Tengo un inconveniente con un sitio web que esta alojado en un servidor Windows Server 2008 R2 (equipado con un procesador Intel Xeon QuadCore y 12 GB de RAM).

Hace dos semanas que todos los días (y varias veces por día) debemos reiniciar el sitio web (desde el IIS) para que vuelva a comenzar a funcionar nuevamente.

Previo al reinicio, la particularidad es que luego de intentarse loguearse al sitio web este deja de responder y queda "esperando" la autenticación (ni siquiera llega a conectarse a la base de datos donde debe verificar la autenticación). 
Ni siquiera arroja un error que nos permita identificar el inconveniente porque queda "infinitamente" "esperando".

Esto le sucede a muchos usuarios del sitio web y cuando este es reiniciado todo vuelve a la normalidad.

Previamente a reiniciarlo verificamos y vemos lo siguiente:

- Tanto el % de consumo del CPU como de la memoria RAM del servidor es bajo.
- Tampoco existen ataques DDos ni nada por el estilo.
- El sitio web tiene su propia Application Pool asignada y está corriendo.

Incluso hemos cambiado el sitio web de servidor (uno con idénticas características) y le sucede lo mismo.

Analizando la codificación del sitio web veo que hace uso excesivo de variables de sesión con respecto a su cantidad y tamaño de datos guardados. Pero, mas allá de esta pésima práctica, no estamos seguros de que ese sea "el inconveniente".

Como y donde puedo detectar si el sitio web llega a un pico de rendimiento y vuela por los aires? Esto sabiendo que el servidor donde corre no se encuentra en su limite de capacidad?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes forma de revisar el código del login? Puedes comprobar que desde ese server tengan acceso al servidor de BD? Tienen habilitados los logs de IIS para esa aplicación? Al subir el sitio después de reiniciar ocurre el error inmediatamente o el tiempo de actividad es aleatorio? Saludos

Comment: Hola, la conexion a la db funciona perfectamente. Tenemos habilitados el log del sitio web, al reiniciar el sitio web este funciona bien por unas horas y luego vuelve a tener el mismo inconveniente. Desde el log del sitio web no vemos nada raro respecto a requests, y es lo único que podemos ver no hay mayor información en el log que los request realizados, cantidades etc..